# How can i fix this mismatching iPhone provisioning problem?

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I recently upgraded to the iPhone 3.0 sdk.  Once i did this, i needed to reinstall the correct provisioning profile on my iPhone.  However, i can no longer deploy to my device when i need to debug things.  In the organizer window i get the following error:

> The iPhone “(my iphone)” doesn’t have
>   the provisioning profile with which
>   the application was signed.
>
> Please add the provisioning profile
>   via the Organizer, or check the “Code
>   Signing Identity” build setting.

I've verified that the profile is in fact installed on the device.  I think my certificate is correct, since i needed to also redo the whole cert request process for another reason.  Has anyone else encountered this error, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure it was the upgrade to 3.0 that caused the problem, and not redoing the cert process?  I just upgraded and had no problems with my certs working (at least as well as they had been working previously).

Comment: Pretty sure; a co-worker of mine is having the same problem and he hasn't recreated his certs/provisions.

Comment: Try rebooting your iPhone -- that's worked for me a couple of times in the past.  Also, in Xcode's Organizer, drag the provisioning profile onto your iPhone icon to make sure the same version is in Xcode and the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what i did to make it work, but it worked after tweaking the product name and identifier in my app's target info, which i'd changed before because of how spaces/underscores don't work as a bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0):

No provisioning problems here - but sometimes I have changed things and forget to update the details on the target and on the main build to the new profile / provisioning certificate.

Have you checked both are now using the new profile / certificate combination.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after simply doing a Build and Run on [a project](http://github.com/jj0b/OverlayViewTester) that I'd just cloned from GitHub.  Performing a Clean All Targets followed by a new Build and Run (presumably with my prov profs this time) cleared it right up.

Probably a rare case; YMMV.